# Hadith: Being thankful to Allah in all occasions

Tags: hadith

[From sunnah.com:](https://sunnah.com/urn/271380)

> Strange are the ways of a believer for there is good in every affair
> of his and this is not the case with anyone else except in the case of
> a believer for if he has an occasion to feel delight, he thanks (God),
> thus there is a good for him in it, and if he gets into trouble and
> shows resignation (and endures it patiently), there is a good for him
> in it. **—Sahih Muslim, Book 55, Hadith 82**

Is there a version of this hadith (or a similar hadith) where it says (something like), “something good happens and **the believer says alhamdulillah**; or something bad happens, and **the believer says alhamdulliah**.”

Comment: https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/33/148

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I looked, there is no hadith specifically like the one you quoted that mentions "Alhamdulillah" in good and bad situations.

However, as commented by UmH already, there is a hadith similar to what you are looking for but it is about the Prophet (SAW):

> "When the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) saw something he liked, he would say: 'Al-hamdu lillahil-ladhi bi ni'matihi tatimmus-salihat (Praise is to Allah by Whose grace good deeds are completed).' And if he saw something that he disliked, he would say: 'Al-hamdu lillahi 'ala kulli hal (Praise is to Allah in all circumstances).'" ([Sunan Ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:3803))

This hadith was considered Sahih by Al-Albani. In addition, Al-Hakim said it has a Sahih isnad. But, as you can see, Darussalam grades it as weak.